# Remove underscore from layer names

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Photoshop added an underscore to all the layers names.

> Layer one --->  Layer_one
> Layer two --->  Layer_two
> Layer three --->  Layer_three

Is there a way to remove the underscore without going though layer by layer manually? A search and replace function?

How can I prevent photoshop from adding the underscore to replace spaces?

Comment: I don't think Photoshop adds underscores in any scenario, maybe some sort of a thirdparty plugin that did that? Other than that to rename them back you'll need a script I believe

Comment: If you are using Photoshop on macOS, this AppleScript will rename all Layer Names containing underscores, to spaces… in the active Photoshop document.  The Layers pallet in Photoshop does not even need to be the active pallet, as long as it is somewhere on your workspace.  Go here —> https://pastebin.com/vu2ApPeq and select the option to download.  Double click  the file after it’s downloaded to your computer and it should automatically open in Script Editor.app and from there you can just run the code.